# Wordwrap Default set to "on" in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there anyway to set WordWrap to "on" by default. in VS-Code Editor. So that even after restarting the editor it stays "on". So that in my whole life I do not have to change it ever again.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Settings (Crtl+,) and search for wordWrap, by default the value is off, turn it on.
Switching to "on" activates word wrap on all documents in Visual Studio Code.
Now, if you open `settings.json`, with (Crtl+Shift+P), `Open Settings (JSON)`,  you will see that `"editor.wordWrap": "on"` will be present.
Every time you restart VScode those settings will be applied.

Comment: Yes, I actually did the same thing earlier but it was not working. Though I tried it again after reinstalling and updating to latest and it is working now even after restart. Might have been some bug. Thanks btw.